# Generating set of semi-random numbers with some guaranteed present

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am attempting to create a Python 3 script which prints out all possible sets of 6 numbers, 4 of which are fixed (*must* appear), but can appear anywhere in the 6. The numbers also must all be between 0 and 9.

For instance, if the "fixed" numbers are `1,2,3,4`, then `1,2,4,3,5,7` is acceptable, `1,2,3,3,4,4` is also acceptable, but `0,4,3,7,8,2` or `8,0,5,6,7,8` are not and should not be printed.

I have attempted so solve this so far, but have run into a mental roadblock when it comes to conceptually understanding where exactly to get started on this.

So far I have attempted to use random.sample, just displaying if the numbers picked are within the range, but ultimately determined that it would not be suitable and that I am most likely barking up the wrong tree here. (I realize that the below is not optimal, just trying to get a working solution. This is just for my personal use for generating 6 digit arma map coordinates, so long as it works I don't overly care what it looks like)

```
import random
count = 0
while count < 4:
    res = random.sample([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],  6)
    if [0, 0, 2, 8] in res:
        print(res);
        count += 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far in the question

Comment: Not sure, if this will work for you but you can consider [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices)?

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi I have attempted `random.choices([0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],weights=[20,20,1,20,1,1,1,1,1,20,1],k=6)`, but am not very familiar with weightings. I _only_ want results which have specific specified numbers in them at least once.

Comment: How about: fix your 4 numbers, then generate the last 2 using your favourite RNG.

Comment: @HongOoi the issue is that the 4 fixed numbers could appear anywhere within the selection.

Comment: Use your favourite shuffle to randomise the order

Comment: @Markyroson why don't you generate sequence and check conditions? If it doesn't fulfill rules, you will regenerate sequence. Weights should guarantee that you will have your sequence correct with high probability and will not have to do too many generations.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi Why use acceptance rejection when it can be done quite directly?

Comment: @pjs you have a good point. I proposed one of the solutions which may not be the optimal for the problem above.

Comment: Your question says that you want a script that "prints out **all** possible sets of 6 numbers [...]". Is that what you want, or do you just want to generate **some** of the possible sets at random? If you want all of them, it's a bit strange to be using the `random` module.

Answer (score 3):

The following takes a specified list of fixed values, determines how many additional random numbers are needed and appends them, then shuffles the list and returns it.

```
import random

def generate_set(fixed_vals = [1, 2, 3, 4], length = 6, min = 0, max = 9):
    for _ in range(length - len(fixed_vals)):
        fixed_vals.append(random.randint(min, max))
    random.shuffle(fixed_vals)
    return fixed_vals

print(generate_set())  # produces, e.g., [0, 3, 4, 8, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution works out for the sequence that should contain `0, 0, 2, 8` (weights specified for this sequence). The solution could be further generalized.

```
def generate_sequence(weights):
    return random.choices([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], weights=weights, k=6)

def check_sequence(sequence, check):
    return check(sequence)

def check():
   # TODO: Add your own implementation of sequence checker
   pass

# You could play with weights to generate sequence with higher probability
weights = [4,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1]  
sequence = generate_sequence(weights)

while check_sequence(sequence, check):
    sequence = generate_sequence(weights)
```